# Setting NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() int32 Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to use NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() with a int32 but i get this error.

```
@IBAction func ChangeBitrate(sender: UISlider) {
        let value = Int32(sender.value)

        print(value)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(value, forKey: "userBitrateKey")

    }
```

I get this error cannot convert value of type int32 how do i store large numbers with NSUserDefaults?

Thanks

Comment: Just store the `Int` value? Is there a reason you need it as `Int32`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Int`.

- On 32 bit machines it's the same as `Int32`
- On 64 bit machines it's `Int64`.

  ```
  let value = Int(sender.value)
  ```

`NSUserDefaults` bridges the value to `NSNumber` anyway.

Comment: Hi @vadian my number is 952802 or higher it just seems to crash my app if i use int

Comment: as soon as i drag the slider i get 2016-04-14 17:41:47.690 Sample-Swift[2723:1017603] Creating context
952802
(lldb)

Comment: The highest `Int32` number is 2147483647. There must be another reason.